# Publisher - Subscriber pattern where subsriber invoke a service

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Publisher - Subscriber pattern where subsriber invoke a service.

Server as a Publisher, registered 10 agents as Subscriber. 
I have successfully implemented this using Publisher-Subscriber pattern.
In my case, one of the agent invoke a service on the server and server notifies to all its registered agents.

Is there any simple way to include this service invocation by agent, in my existing Publisher-Subscriber pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have no single publisher consider switching from publish-subscribe paradigm to event bus.

So your current server should expose API that allows two operations:

> - Event handler registration
> - Event publishing

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This server is an external server, so we don't have any control over it.